# output file is empty vite rollupOptions output option

Tags: vite

I tried below config to output the demo.js into the wwwroot folder. but the output file is empty.

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from '@rollup/plugin-babel';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    resolve(),
    vue(),
    babel({ babelHelpers: 'bundled' })
  ],
  build: {
    rollupOptions: {
      input: 'src/demo.js',
      output: {
        dir: './wwwroot/',
        entryFileNames: '[name].js',
        assetFileNames: '[name].[ext]',
        chunkFileNames: '[name].js'
      }
    }
  },
})
```